# Would Cold-War era nuclear-armed US ABM missiles cause a nationwide EMP effect while intercepting enemy missiles?

Tags: nuclear-weapons

Interceptor missiles armed with high-yield nuclear warheads had flight ceilings of hundreds of miles (such as the Spartan interceptor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIM-49_Spartan)
Given that a single warheads of a few hundred kilotons detonated at ~200 miles in altitude over the United States would have a severe effect on the power grid of the entire country, isn't it likely that the US would actually be severely damaged by its own anti-ballistic missile interceptors causing an EMP effect?

Comment: From what I recall the optimal EMP effect requires specific warheads and detonation altitudes. This would be a much better Q on the physics or engineering stack.

Comment: Ref. to "interceptor missiles armed with high-yield nuclear warheads" - this sounds strange. Aren't these interceptor missiles against missiles high with -yield nuclear warheads? Also, unless it is linked to a political decision/process, this question is more appropriate on [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), I guess.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but has not much to do with politics and should be moved to a diferent SE comunity.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fizz a bit about EMP phenomenon here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41554/12102 and https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43504/12102 I wish there was a "Warfare and Military Technology Stack Exchange for this kind of stuff :-)

Comment: FYI: the Spartan used a special warhead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W71 that was optimized for X-ray output to reduce the EMP/[blackout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_blackout) effect. As they were withdrawn after one year of service in the 1970s, the Q may be also suitable on history SE.

Comment: As I read that latter article, it would have been more of a problem if the attacker detonated a conventional nuclear warhead at that (outer space) altitude at it would have blinded the defense, despite them using special warheads.